# How can I activate my keyboard's microphone mute light when using set-source-mute?

Tags: pulseaudio, thinkpad, pipewire

Give these two commands, the command for `set-sink-mute` turns on the muted light on my keyboard for audio

```
pactl set-sink-mute   @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle
pactl set-source-mute @DEFAULT_SOURCE@ toggle
```

But `set-source-mute` does not turn on the microphone mute light. Is there a way to fix this.

I'm using an Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon with Debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like this should be a function of sof. But I could be *totally* wrong here. Filed an issue anyway on it,

https://github.com/thesofproject/sof/issues/8195

If it should be filed elsewhere, I'll take it elsewhere. But the sound driver should know when the source volume is 0, and it should be able to trigger a light without me writing wrapper that keeps state or tracks it externally.